# Is there a way to update the Configurations of an AWS Lambda Function based on changes to Parameter Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have a group of EC2 instances that will update their configurations based on changes made to specific parameters in Parameter Store. Whenever an instance is deployed, a startup script will read parameter values to know whether to enable or disable certain functionality. These instances get deployed on a periodic basis, so reacting to parameter store changes happen fairly often.

I would like to control the configurations of Lambda Functions (mainly environment variables and Layers) in a similar way - reacting to changes from Parameter Store. However, these Lambda Functions are not deployed in a standard way, so no startup script is included at the moment. These Lambda Functions will not be periodically deployed either.

I would like a suggestion for an appropriate way to implement this functionality. My first thought would be to create an Eventbridge Lambda Function that reacts to specific events in parameter store, though I don't have too much experience with Eventbridge, so I'm not too sure if this is possible.

Alternatively, if there is a better approach to controlling Lambda Functions configurations, that would be nice to know as well.

Comment: Have you looked at AWS AppConfig? Sounds like what you would want. For env variables, lambda itself could modify. For layers you can have a CDK app package the .zip and deploy it. (or manage both layers and env variables through cdk)

Comment: example links: [using appConfig in Lambda](https://medium.com/@davidkelley87/using-aws-appconfig-instead-of-environment-variables-with-lambda-d522b69b5388), [deploying a Lambda from another Lambda](https://dev.to/mraszplewicz/running-aws-cdk-from-a-lambda-function-3502) (that's for the layers problem, you'd just use the [layer-related constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.LayerVersion.html) instead of whatever's in the example)